# Extend django class from module in my view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to extend a Django class providing from external library in my view in order to add some things. It's the first time I'm doing this kind of thing and I need some help.

**In my external module**

I have this class named `EdqmThreadCreateView` :

```
class EdqmThreadCreateView(ForumPermissionMixin, ThreadCreateView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EdqmThreadCreateView, self).__init__()
        self.form_class.base_fields['body'].label = 'Message'

    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        """
        initial = self.initial.copy()

        # Get default topic
        topic_id = self.request.GET.get('topic', None)

        if topic_id:
            initial['topic'] = int(topic_id)

        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """ Save form if it is valid """
        thread = form.save(self.request.user)
        url_redirect = get_absolute_url(thread)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(url_redirect)
```

This class is in `urls.py` file of external module :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^forum/new', EdqmThreadCreateView.as_view(), name='forum-create-thread'),
    ...
]
```

**In my django app**

I would like to use the previous code, but I would like to add some things : change the url, add variables, ...

In my views.py file, I wrote a very easy example to see if my class is called :

```
from edqm.forum.views import EdqmThreadCreateView

class KnowxThreadCreateView(EdqmThreadCreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('this is the class used')
```

And urls.py file :

```
from .views import KnowxThreadCreateView

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^forum/new', KnowxThreadCreateView.as_view(), name='forum-create-thread'),
]
```

If I understand the inherit process, it should work right ? But where Django select the function which will be used if 2 classes called the same url ?

It's a bit unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you *can't* have two views using the same URL. If you need separate functionality provided by a separate view, define a separate URL.

Comment: Ok, but how I can override a class defined inside an external module in my django project view ? Or, How I can import views from my django project to my external module ? Through this way, I can use only one url and define my `KnowxThreadCreateView` for this url ?

Comment: Django processes URL patterns in order. If you define your URL before including the one from your external library, then yours will be called and the external one won't.

Comment: But urls are defined in two different files. If I comment url from external library, I can't access to my new class view with urls define in my django project.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I didn't say anything about commenting. Simply put your own pattern in your own urls.py above where you include the URLs from the external library.

Comment: Ok I understand ! I was not at the good place. I have to set my app url before my external library url in the django project urls.py file and I was in the django app urls.py file .. It seems to be better now ! Thank you !